# Webex floating windows cover parts of the screen for viewers while sharing

Tags: screen-sharing, webex

I have a strange issue with Webex screen sharing. I use the desktop client on Win10, but the issue is happening on other systems too.

When I start screen sharing choosing an application window, not the whole screen, I like to keep the participants and the chat floating windows open, moved to the edge of the screen. The problem is that the silhouettes of these windows are sometimes visible to the viewers, covering parts of the shared content. Sometimes they see rectangles with checkered backgrounds (like what we use to indicate a transparent background). But not every time.

Does anyone have any idea?